# Append two tags to the same row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, attr

How do I append two tags to the same row? Current this is only creating a **td** tag not putting the **a** tag inside of it. This is the desired result.

Desired:

```
<td class="link-text"><a href="#">Click Here</a></td>
```

Current code:

```
var newRow = $('<tr>').attr('id', keyID);
        newRow.append($('<td class="link-text">').text(artist_name));
        newRow.append($('<td><a class="link-text" style="padding:5px;" target="_blank">').attr("href", link).text(link));
        newRow.append($('<td class="link-text">').text(email));
```

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your desired result:

```
<td class="link-text><a href="#">Click Here</a></td>
```

You can do something like this:

First create your `td`, then append your `a` to that `td`, and then append that `td` to your `tr`

```js
var newRow = $('<tr>').attr('id', 51);

var newTd = $('<td class="link-text">');

newTd.append($('<a style="padding:5px;" target="_blank"></a>').attr("href", 'google.com').text('Click here'));

newRow.append(newTd);
        
$('.container').append(newRow);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are adding `href` attribute to the `td` element not the `a` element, so first create a `td` element then add `a` element inside this and then add the `td` to to `tr` element. use like this

```
var newRow = $('<tr>').attr('id', keyID);
newRow.append($('<td class="link-text">').text(artist_name));
var newTd = $('<td class="link-text">');
newTd.append($('<a style="padding:5px;" target="_blank"></a>').attr("href", link).text('Click Here'));
newRow.append(newTd);
newRow.append($('<td class="link-text">').text(email));
$('table tbody').append(newRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("table tbody tr:first").append('<td class="link-text"><a href="#">Click Here</a></td>');
        });
```